# Connecting 2 separate branch together [istgame]

Tags: game-tree, istgame

I'm a beginner with istgame and TikZ, but is there a way I can make the game tree(s) below? I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: the answer below is a step towards your requirement -- please see the documentation at http://ctan.imsc.res.in/graphics/pgf/contrib/istgame/istgame-doc.pdf  -- I only had to read section 1 in about 30mins to get the answer in the form below -- the remaining tree is only an extension of the same code -- in case of difficulty please revert

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{istgame}
        \xtdistance{15mm}{30mm}
        \istroot(0)(0,0){B\textsubscript{1}} % root as (0) at (0,0)
            \istb [above right]{P\textsubscript{1}}% endpoint will be (0-1)
%           \istb % endpoint will be (0-2), automatically
%           \istb % endpoint will be (0-3), automatically
            \endist % end of simple (parent-child) structure
        \istroot(c)(0-1) % names the subroot (c) at (0-3)
            \istb % endpoint will be (c-1)
            \istb % endpoint will be (c-2)
            \endist
        \istroot(d)(c-2)
            \istb 
            \istb 
            \endist 
        \istroot(e)(d-2)
            \istb 
            \istb 
            \endist 
        \istroot(f)[right=5cm of c-2]{B\textsubscript{1}}
            \istb 
            \istb
            \endist 
        \istroot(g)(f-2){B\textsubscript{1}} 
            \istb 
            \istb
            \endist
        \xtInfoset(e)(g){}
    \end{istgame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: -1 can someone explain the reason